# PHP - Regex to match if ban command

Tags: php, regex

I have a regex like this in PHP:

```
$msg = "ban:Joan24@Jump123" // Jump123 = password, Joan24 = user

if (preg_match($msg, "/ban:[A-Za-z0-9]@Jump123/")) // Not working -.-
```

If it works, it should return true, but it doesn't, why, and how do I fix this?

Comment: `[^...]` means *not* one of these characters...

Comment: `ban:[A-Za-z0-9]` it matches one character after `:` which may be from `A-Z or a-z or 0-9`. To match one or more characters, you have to add `+` sign after `[A-Za-z0-9]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`[^A-Za-z0-9]` matches everything but alphanumeric characters. `/ban:[A-Za-z0-9]+@Jump123/"` (without the "up-caret" in the character class) will match your input message.

Comment: Just tested that and it didn't seem to do the trick.  I think there needs to be a '+' or '*' after the alphanumeric character

Answer (score 1):

First, preg_match is pattern, variable.
Second, the pattern must be between simple '
If you want to complete the regular expression with a concrete character pattern, you can add .*.
Your Pattern tries to find not character.

```
    $msg = "ban:Joan24@Jump123"; // Jump123 = password, Joan24 = user
    if (preg_match('/ban:[A-Za-z0-9].*@Jump123/',$msg )) {
        print "TRUE";
    } else {
        print "FALSE";
    }
    $msg = "bOn:Joan24@Jump123"; // Jump123 = password, Joan24 = user
    if (preg_match('/ban:[A-Za-z0-9].*@Jump123/',$msg )) {
        print "TRUE";
    } else {
        print "FALSE";
    }
    $msg = "ban:1245@Jump123"; // Jump123 = password, Joan24 = user
    if (preg_match('/ban:[A-Za-z0-9].*@Jump123/',$msg )) {
        print "TRUE";
    } else {
        print "FALSE";
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct syntax for [`preg_match()`](http://www.php.net/preg_match) is:

```
int preg_match ( string $pattern , string $subject [, array &$matches [, int $flags = 0 [, int $offset = 0 ]]] )
```

Also, the [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) `[A-Za-z0-9]` in your regular expression only matches **`1`** character of `A` to `Z`, `a` to `z`, `0` to `9`, you need to place a [**quantifier**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) after your character class.

Final solution: ( included the `i` modifier for case-insensitive matching )

```
$msg = 'ban:Joan24@Jump123';
if (preg_match('/ban:[a-z0-9]+@Jump123/i', $msg)) { 
  // do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[This regex](http://regex101.com/r/rH9aD3) seems to do the trick, although I wouldn't consider myself an expert:

```
if (preg_match($msg, "/ban:[A-Za-z0-9]+@Jump123/")) // Note the '+' after the alphanumeric for 1 or more characters
```